# why serverScoket.accept() execute several times about only one request

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tomcat, serversocket

I am learning the book *how tomcat works* and find a thing which make me a big surprise. I simplify the code as below:

```
public class Boot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerDemo server = new ServerDemo();
        try {
            server.start();
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
}
```

---

```
public class ServerDemo implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("--receive request from client----"+
                    Thread.currentThread().getId());
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the `Boot` class is *Main class* and used to boot this application and the `ServerDemo` class is a simplified server which listen **8080** port and will print info when a request from **browser** reach. 
Now the **question** is that: I think when I make a *request* from browser it will execute

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

and then print info **only once** and then thread block itself because of `accept method` waiting the next request.

**But** the real is that the thread print info **several times:(maybe 3,4..)** about a request.

and this is a executing:
input:

```
http://localhost:8080/index
```

output:

```
--receive request from client----13
--receive request from client----13
--receive request from client----13
```

**my expected output:**

--receive request from client----number

summary: I cant figure out about **one** request why it prints **several times** it means **accept method** execute several times.

Comment: Its probably your browser trying a few different things to get you to response cause you just closed the connection on them. Try using `curl` or `wget` instead.

Comment: @ ug_ Yes, when the client dont reveive response it will try once again.

Comment: Correct. Your issue is based upon the assumption that the browser is making 1 request when in fact it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your browser trying a few different things to get you to response cause you just closed the connection on them. Try using `curl` or `wget` instead.
                    – ug_